# Cannot redeclare Aws\constantly() (previously declared in /var/www/html/axcessio/aws_new/Aws/functions.php:19)

Tags: sugarcrm

```
$EC2client = EC2client::factory(array(
                                        'credentials.cache' => $cacheAdapter,
                                         'version' => '2016-11-15',
                                         'region'  => 'us-west-1',
                                        ));
```

Cannot redeclare Aws\constantly() (previously declared in /var/www/html/axcessio/aws_new/Aws/functions.php:19) in /var/www/html/microservices/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php on line 22

Comment: Can you please provide some further details?

Comment: i am using scheduler,,  added this files which is causing this error
require_once('modules/Users/User.php');
include'../microservices/vendor/autoload.php';
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache;
use Aws\DoctrineCacheAdapter;
$cacheAdapter = new DoctrineCacheAdapter(new FilesystemCache('/tmp/cache'));
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

Comment: are you calling this EC2client::factory in a loop ?